# Type a matrix in beamer

Tags: beamer, matrices

I want to input the matrix which is shown in the screenshot. How to input the code in beamer?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @Mico, I have reedited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & \cdots{} & 0 & c_{1,r+1} & \cdots{} & c_{1n}\\
  0 & 1 & \cdots{} & 0 & c_{2,r+1} & \cdots{} & c_{2n}\\
  \vdots{} & \vdots{} &  & \vdots{} & \vdots{} &  & \vdots{}\\
  0 & 0 & \cdots{} & 1 & c_{r,r+1} & \cdots{} & c_{rn}\\
  0 & 0 & \cdots{} & 0 & 0 & \cdots{} & 0\\
  \vdots{} & \vdots{} &  & \vdots{} & \vdots{} &  & \vdots{}\\
  0 & 0 & \cdots{} & 0 & 0 & \cdots{} & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. `\cdots` and `\vdots` don't take arguments; the 20 `{}` terms thus do nothing except create code clutter. The screenshot you posted doesn't look like it was generated by the code you posted.

Comment: The last row is not what is expected.

Comment: @mico : I'm a AUCTeX user. this is a feature for inserting any macro. I do not think it make much trouble both for the computer and the reader.

Comment: @F. Pantigny It is very fortunate that there are reviewers on tex.SE. I shouldn't let myself go to this facility

Comment: @gigiair， Thanks a lot. If I want to get the following form $A$=the above matrix, how to change the code?

Comment: @mathbeginer Just replace \\[ ... \\] with $ ... $